Nash embedding theorem for Hessian metric
Suppose we have manifold with single chart $(M, \theta)$, and metric defined in coordinates as
$$ g_{ij}(\theta) = \partial_i\partial_j\Psi(\theta) $$
for some smooth, strictly convex function $\Psi\colon \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$. Is there a geometrical way of thinking about $M$ as being graph of some function?

This question is motivated by usage of such objects in Information geometry and dually flat manifolds. I would like to gain some better geometric intuitions about the metric here.
